# Conditions - Differentiate pull request and pull request merge

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Let's say I have a pipeline `my-pipeline` which 1) Install dependencies 2) Test my application.

I set up a build validation policy which triggers `my-pipeline` upon creation of a pull request.

Once the pull request is approved and merged, `my-pipeline` is triggered again.

### Questions

Is there a way to differentiate the creation of the PR and the merged of the PR within my `yaml` file, so I can use conditions to trigger some scripts on creation but not on merge. Something similar to `condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['build.reason'], 'PullRequest'))`

For instance, I would trigger `test` on PR creation but not after the merge

Comment: You have mentioned checking build.reason, which seems like enough to me?  What specifically do you want to achieve?

You can differentiate between your `main` branch, your feature branches and your merge builds from pull requests.  Perhaps `'Build.SourceBranch'` might be relevant?  (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Once the PR is created, a branch XXXXX/merge will be created (where XXXXX is the PR number).  This merge branch is used in any pull request builds.  Any pull request build will have build.reason set to PullRequest, as you mention in the question.

Builds triggered by either a VCS or schedule trigger on your normal branches (this likely includes your `main` branch and may include your feature branches from which you create pull requests into `main`) will have a different build.reason.  If you have a VCS trigger on `main` it will trigger after the PR completes. What more is required?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml gives some examples of helpful conditions, perhaps that will help?